# Execute a Jmeter process as a Azure service?

Tags: azure-devops

I there anyone who has configured a jmeter task (which will run for more than 20 -30 hours) as an azure service.

The issue I'm facing is at the moment I'm running Jmeter tests on an Azure VM.
Some time it's hard to use that VM due to high resource utilization and the cost of the VM.
So is there any other way to run my same Jmeter task on azure?

*I tried with Pipeline and looking for something else.*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where the Cloud Agent would timeout after an hour and so I just spun up a VM on Azure and used Windows Task Scheduler to run the tests each night and upload the results (via Git).

The results viewer (under Test Plans > Runs) in Azure was setup to pull those results from git. To add those results I setup a Pipeline task that ran before work started so that all the results overnight had time to wrap up. Here is the YAML:

```
steps:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/TestResults/*.trx'
    testRunTitle: 'My Project'
```

Comment: Hmmm.That was a brilliant idea "The results viewer (under Test Plans > Runs) in Azure was setup to pull those results from git." can I get some guidelines on how to do that.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the YAML from my Azure Pipeline task. The VM runs at midnight and the Pipeline runs at 4am.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was running UI tests but there should be a publisher for JMeter, too.